# Sector number for NTFS details

Tags: ntfs

I have a SSD on which I created a NTFS volume.

Which LBA/Sector contains the NTFS information like the sample below?

```
    0000:  EB 52 90 4E 54 46 53 20 20 20 20 00 02 08 00 00  .R.NTFS    .....
    0010:  00 00 00 00 00 F8 00 00 3F 00 FF 00 3F 00 00 00  ........?...?...
    0020:  00 00 00 00 80 00 80 00 AE 39 D7 00 00 00 00 00  .........9......
    0030:  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 8D EF 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
     so on
```

When I queried sector 0x0 I got the following..

```
    LBA: 0x0000000000000000 (0)
    Offset  Byte Dump                                        ASCII Dump
    ------  -----------------------------------------------  ----------------
     0x000  33 c0 8e d0 bc 00 7c 8e c0 8e d8 be 00 7c bf 00  3.....|......|..
     0x010  06 b9 00 02 fc f3 a4 50 68 1c 06 cb fb b9 04 00  .......Ph.......
     0x020  bd be 07 80 7e 00 00 7c 0b 0f 85 0e 01 83 c5 10  ....~..|........
     0x030  e2 f1 cd 18 88 56 00 55 c6 46 11 05 c6 46 10 00  .....V.U.F...F..
     0x040  b4 41 bb aa 55 cd 13 5d 72 0f 81 fb 55 aa 75 09  .A..U..]r...U.u.
     0x050  f7 c1 01 00 74 03 fe 46 10 66 60 80 7e 10 00 74  ....t..F.f`.~..t
     0x060  26 66 68 00 00 00 00 66 ff 76 08 68 00 00 68 00  &fh....f.v.h..h.
     0x070  7c 68 01 00 68 10 00 b4 42 8a 56 00 8b f4 cd 13  |h..h...B.V.....
     0x080  9f 83 c4 10 9e eb 14 b8 01 02 bb 00 7c 8a 56 00  ............|.V.
     0x090  8a 76 01 8a 4e 02 8a 6e 03 cd 13 66 61 73 1c fe  .v..N..n...fas..
     0x0a0  4e 11 75 0c 80 7e 00 80 0f 84 8a 00 b2 80 eb 84  N.u..~..........
     0x0b0  55 32 e4 8a 56 00 cd 13 5d eb 9e 81 3e fe 7d 55  U2..V...]...>.}U
     0x0c0  aa 75 6e ff 76 00 e8 8d 00 75 17 fa b0 d1 e6 64  .un.v....u.....d
     0x0d0  e8 83 00 b0 df e6 60 e8 7c 00 b0 ff e6 64 e8 75  ......`.|....d.u
     0x0e0  00 fb b8 00 bb cd 1a 66 23 c0 75 3b 66 81 fb 54  .......f#.u;f..T
     0x0f0  43 50 41 75 32 81 f9 02 01 72 2c 66 68 07 bb 00  CPAu2....r,fh...
     0x100  00 66 68 00 02 00 00 66 68 08 00 00 00 66 53 66  .fh....fh....fSf
     0x110  53 66 55 66 68 00 00 00 00 66 68 00 7c 00 00 66  SfUfh....fh.|..f
     0x120  61 68 00 00 07 cd 1a 5a 32 f6 ea 00 7c 00 00 cd  ah.....Z2...|...
     0x130  18 a0 b7 07 eb 08 a0 b6 07 eb 03 a0 b5 07 32 e4  ..............2.
     0x140  05 00 07 8b f0 ac 3c 00 74 09 bb 07 00 b4 0e cd  ......<.t.......
     0x150  10 eb f2 f4 eb fd 2b c9 e4 64 eb 00 24 02 e0 f8  ......+..d..$...
     0x160  24 02 c3 49 6e 76 61 6c 69 64 20 70 61 72 74 69  $..Invalid parti
     0x170  74 69 6f 6e 20 74 61 62 6c 65 00 45 72 72 6f 72  tion table.Error
     0x180  20 6c 6f 61 64 69 6e 67 20 6f 70 65 72 61 74 69   loading operati
     0x190  6e 67 20 73 79 73 74 65 6d 00 4d 69 73 73 69 6e  ng system.Missin
     0x1a0  67 20 6f 70 65 72 61 74 69 6e 67 20 73 79 73 74  g operating syst
     0x1b0  65 6d 00 00 00 63 7b 9a 86 a5 ec 84 00 00 00 20  em...c{........
     0x1c0  21 00 07 fe ff ff 00 08 00 00 00 e8 bf 12 00 00  !...............
     0x1d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
     0x1e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
     0x1f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  ..............U.
```

Comment: What is your actaull question?

Comment: I want to know in which LBA does the string "NTFS" appear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that you probably need this information anymore, but what you are seeing at sector 0 is the [Master Boot Sector](https://www.minitool.com/lib/boot-sector.html) (sometimes called the MBR).  Among other things, it contains a list of the partitions on the disk.

Each of the disk's partitions contains its own boot record.  In this case, the block that contains "NTFS    " is an [NTFS Partition Boot Sector](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-partition-boot-sector.htm).